# Inheritance issue on submenu list items in an unordered list

Tags: html, css

I'm adapting a responsive mobile menu so that it appears as a fullscreen layout across a variety of mobile device screen sizes, therefore I am using a percentage for the width of the links (85%) instead of a fixed value as I am on larger screens.

I have the `li` set to `width:100%` and the `a` tags set to `width:85%`. On subordinate list items I have added 14px padding on the left hand side in order to make them stand out visually. The problem is that with the padding on  the left, the list items become wider with each level of the menu.

The only two ways I've found to fix this have caused new problems. For example, I tried making both the `li` and the `a` tag 100% width, but this causes the 1px border on the bottom to lose the margin on either side, making the border full width.

Secondly I tried making the list item 85% width and setting the `a` to 100%, but this cuts off some of the padding on the submenu buttons, meaning that you can't click the whole button.

Am I missing something simple here? Any insight would be great.

https://jsfiddle.net/8nj5y4t1/48/

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="main-menu" id="mobile">
    <div class="menu-header-menu-container">
        <ul id="menu-header-menu-1" class="menu">
            <li class="hide-desktop menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1386"><a href="http://www.mywebsite.com">Link 1</a></li>
            <li class="open menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-463"><a href="http://www.mywebsite.comwork/">Link 2</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-584"><a href="http://www.mywebsite.comwork/landscapes/">Child-link 1</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-473"><a href="http://www.mywebsite.comwork/seascapes/">Child-link 2</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-478"><a href="http://www.mywebsite.comwork/macro/">Child-link 3</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-477"><a href="http://www.mywebsite.comwork/cities/">Child-link 4</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-475"><a href="http://www.mywebsite.comwork/long-exposure/">Child-link 5</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-480"><a href="http://www.mywebsite.comwork/miscellaneous/">Grandchild-link 1</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-10"><a href="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/about/">Link 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-464"><a href="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/shop/">Link 4</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14"><a href="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/contact/">Link 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
nav.main - menu# mobile {
    width: 400 px;
}

nav.main - menu# mobile ul {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav.main - menu# mobile ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline - block;
    float: left;
    width: 100 % ;
    margin: 0 px;
    background - color: grey;
}

nav.main - menu# mobile ul li a {
    display: inline - block;
    height: auto;
    width: 85 % ;
    margin: 0 px 7.5 % 0 px 7.5 % ;
    padding: 15 px 0 px 15 px 0 px;
    background - color: pink;
    color: #888888;
  border-bottom: 1px solid # F1F1F1;
    text - decoration: none!important;
}

.submenu - button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 8 px;
    float: right;
    width: 15 px;
    height: 19 px;
    padding: 17 px;
    background - color: purple;
    cursor: pointer;
}

nav.main - menu# mobile ul ul {
    max - height: 0;
    transition: all 1.2 s;
}

nav.main - menu# mobile ul ul.open {
    max - height: 1000 px;
}

nav.main - menu# mobile ul ul li {
    margin: 0;
    transition: all 1 s;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1.5 s!important;
}

nav.main - menu# mobile ul ul li.open {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1 s!important;
}

nav.main - menu# mobile ul ul li a {
    padding: 15 px 0 15 px 14 px;
}

nav.main - menu# mobile ul ul ul li a {
    padding: 15 px 0 15 px 28 px;
}
```

Comment: Can share screenshot what exact you are looking for...I mean your designed UI.?

Comment: Can your share the exact UI screenshot of this menu ?

Comment: Okay thanks...I will check it.

Comment: I'm worked on your demo with pure css...in your code it has some bugs. (CSS & JS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your menu it has some issues. The best way I decided to create pure CSS menu like your reference website. It's simple and elegant.

Please check the demo

**CSS - Responsive Menu**

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=roboto);
body {
  background: #212121;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word !important;
  font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}

h3 a { color: #FFF; }

a { color: #FFF; }

h1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 70px;
  font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
}

#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 890px;
}

p { text-align: center; }
 .toggle, [id^=drop] {
 display: none;
}

nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #254441;
}

#logo {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 30px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background-color: #254441;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
 -moz-transition:    all .3s ease-out;
 -ms-transition:     all .3s ease-out;
 -o-transition:      all .3s ease-out;
 transition:         all .3s ease-out;
}

nav ul li ul li:hover { background: #000000; }
nav a:hover { background-color: #000000; }

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul { display: inherit; }

nav ul ul li {
  width: 170px;
  float: none;
  display: list-item;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul ul ul li {
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
  left: 170px;
}

li > a:after { content: ' +'; }
li > a:only-child:after { content: ''; }

/* Media Queries
--------------------------------------------- */

@media all and (max-width : 959px) {

#logo { display: none; }

nav { margin: 0; }

.toggle + a,
 .menu { display: none; }

.toggle {
  display: block;
  background-color: #254441;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
}

.toggle:hover { background-color: #000000; }

[id^=drop]:checked + ul { display: block; }

nav ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1f1f1f;
}

nav ul ul .toggle,
nav ul ul a { padding: 0 40px; }
nav ul ul ul a { padding: 0 80px; }
nav a:hover,
nav ul ul ul a { background-color: #000000; }
nav ul li ul li .toggle,
nav ul ul a { background-color: #212121; }
nav ul ul {
  float: none;
  position: static;
  color: #ffffff;
}
nav ul ul li:hover > ul,
nav ul li:hover > ul { display: none; }
nav ul ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2b2929;
}
nav ul ul ul li { position: static; }
.toggle span {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      background-color: #888888;
      padding: 0 20px;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width : 330px) {
nav ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<nav>
  <div id="logo">Responsive Menu</div>
  <label for="drop" class="toggle">Menu <span><i class="fa fa-bars fa-1"></i></span></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
      <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
      <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">Service <span>+</span></label>
      <a href="#">Service</a>
      <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1"/>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Service 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Service 3</a></li>
          </ul>
    </li>
    <li>

      <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
      <label for="drop-2" class="toggle">Portfolio <span>+</span></label>
      <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2"/>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio 2</a></li>
        <li>

          <!-- Second Tier Drop Down -->
          <label for="drop-3" class="toggle">Works <span>+<span></label>
          <a href="#">Works</a>
          <input type="checkbox" id="drop-3"/>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">HTML/CSS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Python</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Submit</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**JS+CSS - Demo (Original)**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('<span class="submenu-button">+</span>').insertBefore('nav.main-menu#mobile ul li:not(.hide-mobile) ul').parent('li');
    $('.submenu-button').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        $(this).next().toggleClass('open').children('li').toggleClass('open').find('ul, .submenu-button').removeClass('open');
    });

});
```

```css
nav.main-menu#mobile {
    width: 400px;
}
nav.main-menu#mobile ul {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 13px 0 .5px;
    /*this line was edited*/
}
nav.main-menu#mobile ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: grey;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*this line is new*/
}
nav.main-menu#mobile ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0px 7.5% 0px 7.5%;
    padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
    background-color: pink;
    color: #888888;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F1F1F1;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
.submenu-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 29px;
    float: right;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 17px 20px;
    background-color: purple;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1;
}
.sub-menu .submenu-button{
    right: 16px;
}
nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul {
    max-height: 0;
    transition: all 1.2s;
}
nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul.open {
    max-height: 1000px;
}
nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul li {
    margin: 0;
    transition: all 1s;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1.5s !important;
}
nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul li.open {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s !important;
}
nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul li a {
    padding: 15px 0 15px 14px;
}
nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul ul li a {
    padding: 15px 0 15px 23px;
    /*this line was edited*/
}

/*----Below this line is new----*/
li.menu-item.menu-item-type-post_type.menu-item-object-page.menu-item-480.open {
    padding-left: 1px;
}
nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul li a {
    padding: 15px 0 15px 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="main-menu" id="mobile">
  <div class="menu-header-menu-container">
    <ul id="menu-header-menu-1" class="menu">
      <li class="hide-desktop menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1386">
        <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com">Link 1
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="open menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-463">
        <a href="http://www.mywebsite.comwork/">Link 2
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-584">
            <a href="http://www.mywebsite.comwork/landscapes/">Child-link 1
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-473">
            <a href="http://www.mywebsite.comwork/seascapes/">Child-link 2
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-478">
            <a href="http://www.mywebsite.comwork/macro/">Child-link 3
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-477">
            <a href="http://www.mywebsite.comwork/cities/">Child-link 4
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-475">
            <a href="http://www.mywebsite.comwork/long-exposure/">Child-link 5
            </a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-480">
                <a href="http://www.mywebsite.comwork/miscellaneous/">Grandchild-link 1
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-10">
        <a href="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/about/">Link 3
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-464">
        <a href="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/shop/">Link 4
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14">
        <a href="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/contact/">Link 5
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi Sayed, this looks great, but I'm not sure I can apply it to my problem as my menu structure is created via PHP and I don't have direct access to the html structure, hence why there are a few jQuery tricks for things like adding the submenu buttons to parent links etc. What are the bugs you found in the code I had? Thanks, Jack

Comment: Hi Jack, I have fixed your menu with your given code. Please check it once.

Comment: @Jack, If you are going to use my example as reference, might as well accept it as the answer. Or is there something I did not cover?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are looking to do, the code below may work.  I only modified the CSS included in the JSfiddle link.

**CSS:**

```
nav.main-menu#mobile {
  width: 400px;
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 13px 0 .5px;          /*this line was edited*/
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: hidden;               /*this line is new*/
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0px 7.5% 0px 7.5%;
  padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
  background-color: pink;
  color: #888888;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F1F1F1;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.submenu-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 8px;
  float: right;
  width: 15px;
  height: 19px;
  padding: 17px;
  background-color: purple;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;                          /*this line is new*/
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: all 1.2s;
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul.open {
  max-height: 1000px;
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul li {
  margin: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1.5s !important;
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul li.open {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s !important;
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul li a {
  padding: 15px 0 15px 14px;
}

nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul ul li a {
  padding: 15px 0 15px 23px;             /*this line was edited*/
}

                /*----Below this line is new----*/

li.menu-item.menu-item-type-post_type.menu-item-object-page.menu-item-480.open {
        padding-left: 1px;
    }

    nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul li a {
        padding: 15px 0 15px 12px;
      }
```